# How can control the items in view class queryset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-guardian

```
class ModelListCreateView(GetQuerysetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = get_objects_for_user(self.context['request'].user, 'model.view_model')
    serializer_class = ModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
```

In the above code snippet am trying to get query only the items a given user is supposed to see. I tried  `queryset = get_objects_for_user(request.user, 'model.view_model')` but this did not work and resulted in an error 'request' not defined. After googling and trying what I have now I get the error 'self' not defined. And am also trying to implement django-guardian on top of the other permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the request object, then override `get_queryset` instead of setting `queryset`.

```
class ModelListCreateView(GetQuerysetMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return get_objects_for_user(self.request.user, 'model.view_model')
```